# Is it ok to simply cache every search using a CachingWrapperFilter?

Tags: caching, lucene, lucene.net

Using Lucene.Net 3.0.3 it is very easy to simply wrap every query created in response to a user's search in a [`CachingWrapperFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html). Would this be a bad idea because Lucene would consume more and more memory, or would Lucene manage memory and release cached items in an intelligent way?

Should I be selective in the queries I wrap in the CachingWrapperFilter?

```
Query query = .... 
QueryWrapperFilter queryFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(query);
CachingWrapperFilter cachingFilter = new CachingWrapperFilter(queryFilter);
searcher.search(query, cachingFilter, 1);
```

#### Update

The Lucene.Net implementation of `CachingWrapperFilter` also uses a mechanism that is tied to Garbage Collection. It implements a `WeakDictionary` class that is keyed using instances of the [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.weakreference.aspx) class. This is a built in .Net class that wraps any object and provides a way to check if that object has been garbage collected or not. This suggests to me that the answer to my question is Yes. The memory management of the Lucene cache will be kept under control because it is essentially tied to the runtime garbage collector and cache items are maintained as long as they are still valid.

#### A bit more detail...

The keys for the cache are provided by the `IndexReader` before being wrapped in a `WeakReference`. The `IndexReader` manages the objects that it provides as cache keys. When they are no longer valid they are disposed and are subsequently garbage collected. The cache can then detect this through the `WeakReference` and remove the item from the cache.

Through the Weak Reference mechanism the `IndexReader` and cache can be disconnected. The `IndexReader` controls the validity of cache items by disposing the key objects, and the cache cleans itself up.

Answer (score 3):

In Java Lucene, this particular cache is using [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) which means that entries will be cleared automagically once the memory pressure intensifies. If there's a counterpart for `WeakHashMap` in .NET, I'd expect it to be used as well.

Comment: The `WeakHashMap` will remove entries when the key is no longer referenced. As a result it avoids a common memory 'leak' when using maps, but it won't respond any differently to memory pressure (though the gc may not run for a while).